# How to add and configure JDK 11 on Linux mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, java, jdk

I'm having trouble to configure oracle JDK 11 to the system. 
I have extracted the JDK and ran the following in the terminal

```
~$ export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11.0.2
~$ export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I also did execute the command

```
~$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java" 1
```

and I removed the IceTea Browser plug-in (recommend by[1](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/java.html))
When I run the java -version command I get the following

```
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

while I run the javac -version I get the following result **javac 11.0.2**

[Note]: I performed the java configuration related actions via referring to multiple sources (YouTube videos, Linux Mint forum & other random places)

Comment: Well, I guess you (still) have OpenJDK version 10.0.2 installed, right?  If you’re willing to uninstall that, that would be a good step. Otherwise, try ``PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`` so it finds the new version.

Comment: @G-Man So it is ok to uninstall the OpenJDK version? Got some feedback in the forum it's better not to uninstall it.

Comment: @G-Man I did execute the path command provided from your side and it worked. But when I reboot my system it again point to the OpenJDK, so any suggestion in there how to configure it just once

Comment: Put the `export` commands into your `.bashrc` or ``.bash_profile`` file.

Comment: @G-Man I have further question 
what is the difference b/w PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
and PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: `PATH` defines where the shell looks for programs (like `cat`, `ls`, `java` and `javac`). It is searched from left to right. If you say `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`, you put `$JAVA_HOME/bin` (`/opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin`) at the beginning of `PATH`, so it looks there first. If you say `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`, you put `$JAVA_HOME/bin` at the end of `PATH` — and the directory of OpenJDK version 10.0.2 is in the current `PATH` value somewhere, so it will be found rather than 11.0.2.

Comment: @G-Man Thanks for the explanation and It really helped. 
Appreciate the effort. In early stages of using Linux, feel relieved when  getting answers from the community

Answer (score 1):

Following https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80216/g-man I was able to solve this scenario in the following way and also looking to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWJPVcaubyM

- Downloaded and extracted the Oracle JDK to the specific directory [in my case it was: `usr/lib/jvm`]
- Set the global environment variable for Java by following steps:

  1. Go to prodile.d folder via Terminal [`cd /etc/profile.d/`]
  2. Open text editor (**xed**)
  3. `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11`
     `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`
- Save the file as `java.sh`
- The `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` helps to detect the desired JDK while the Open JDK is still installed.